# Some sort of commutativity of circulant matrices with a certain transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, circulant-matrices

Given a vector $v = (a_0, a_1, a_2, ... , a_n)$, we call a $k$-circulant matrix $C_k(v)$, where $k \geq n$, the following $k*k$ matrix :
$$ C_k(v)= \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_n & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_n & 0 & ... \\
\cdot &  &  &  & \cdot &  &  \\
 & \cdot &  &  &  & \cdot &  \\
 &  & \cdot &  &  &  & \cdot \\
a_3 & a_4 & ... & a_n & 0 & ... & 0 \\
a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & ... & a_n & 0 & ... 
\end{bmatrix}  $$
(basically, you pad the vector with zeros and then you form a circulant matrix with it.)

For simplicity, given two natural numbers $n,k$, define the block-matrix $$I_{n,k} = \begin{bmatrix}
I_n & I_n & ... & I_n 
\end{bmatrix}  $$
where $I_n$ repeats k times (I_n is the identity matrix of order $n$.)

I found out that, given a vector $v = (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ of length $n$ and a natural number $k$, we have the following relation: 
$$ C_n(v) \cdot I_{n,k} = I_{n,k}\cdot C_{nk}(v)$$

This really isn't that hard to prove, since if for the vector $v$ we consider the following matrices:
$$ B =  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 &...  & 0 \\
a_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
a_{n - 1}& a_n & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
a_{n - 2} & a_{n-1} & a_n & 0 & ... & 0  \\ 
& & \cdot & & & \\
& & &\cdot & & \\
& & & & \cdot &  \\
a_{2} & a_{3} & ... & a_{n-1} & a_n& 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

$$A =  \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & ... & a_n \\
0 & a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_{n-1} \\
& & \cdot \\
& & & \cdot \\
& & & & \cdot \\
0 & 0 & ... & 0 & a_1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

we observe that $C_n(v) = A+B$,
$$C_{n,k} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B & 0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & A & B & 0 & ... & 0\\
&& \cdot \\
&&& \cdot \\
&&&& \cdot \\
B & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & A
\end{bmatrix},  $$

and so the relation to prove becomes
$$ [ A + B ] \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
I_n & I_n & ... & I_n 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
I_n & I_n & ... & I_n 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
A & B & 0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & A & B & 0 & ... & 0\\
&& \cdot \\
&&& \cdot \\
&&&& \cdot \\
B & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & A
\end{bmatrix}, $$

which is obvious.

However, here comes the question: I have tested that given two vectors $v = (a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n) $ and $w = (b_1, b_2, ... , b_n)$, the following is also true:
$$ C_n(v) \cdot C_n(w) \cdot I_{n,k} = I_{n,k} \cdot C_{nk}(v) \cdot C_{nk}(w) $$

I haven't been able to prove this one; I know that the product of two circulant matrices is also a circulant matrix, but it doesn't seem like there is a vector $z = (c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$ such that $C_n(v) \cdot C_n(w) = C_n(z)$ and $  C_{nk}(v) \cdot C_{nk}(w)  = C_{nk}(z)$.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically we have
$$C_n(w) \cdot \begin{bmatrix} C_n(v) & C_n(v) & ... & C_n(v) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} C_n(v) & C_n(v) & ... & C_n(v) \end{bmatrix} \cdot C_{nk} (w) $$

By splitting $C_{nk} (w) $ into matrices $X$ and $Y$, we want to show that
$$\begin{bmatrix} C_{n}(w)C_n(v) & C_{n}(w) C_n(v) & ... & C_{n}(w)C_n(v) \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} C_n(v) & C_n(v) & ... & C_n(v) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} X & Y & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & X & Y & 0 & ... & 0 \\ &&\cdot \\ &&&\cdot \\ &&&&\cdot \\ Y & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & X \end{bmatrix} ,$$
which is obvious, since $ X+Y = C_n(w)$,